# Determine complex numbers uniquely from their combinations

Tags: complex-numbers

Say I know the quantities, $|z_{1}|^2$, $|z_{2}|^2$, $z_{1} z_{2}^{*}$ and $z_{1}^{*} z_{2}$. And the idea is to know $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$.

If I write $z_{1} = r_{1} \exp(i \phi_{1} )$ and $z_{2} = r_{2} \exp(i \phi_{2} )$, I can immediately find $\phi_{1} - \phi_{2} = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\text{Im}(z_{1} z_{2}^{*})}{\text{Re}(z_{1} z_{2}^{*})} \right)$.

I cannot figure out how to find another equation, involving a combination of $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$. It should be possible to determine $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$, since I have $4$ equations with $4$ unknowns ($2$ real numbers for each $z$).

Comment: Essentially you only have 3 independent equations, noting that $z_1z_2^*=(z_1^*z_2)^*$. So we can deduce $r_1,r_2$ from the first two equations and deduce $\phi_1-\phi_2$ fromthe last two equations, if the last two equations are adaptive.

Comment: That's right. It was an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to determine $z_1$ and $z_2$ uniquely. For example, $z_1=z_2=1$ and $z_1=-1, z_2=-1$ both give the same values for $|z_1|^{2},|z_2|^{2},z_1^{*}z_2$ and $z_1z_2^{*}$.

Comment: I think you meant $z_{1} = z_{2} = -1$.

Comment: @sbp Thanks. That was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $$z_1=r_1e^{i\theta_1},\ z_2=r_2e^{i\theta_2}$$ is a solution.  Then so is  $$z_1'=e^{i\theta}z_1,\ z_2'=re^{i\theta}z_2$$ for any real number $\theta$.